# Difference between topologies generated by a basis and a subbasis

Tags: general-topology

I am looking for examples where topologies generated by a subbasis and a basis yield to the same topologies, preferably in a finite topological space.

For instance let $X=\{1,2,3\}$. The collection $\mathcal{S} = \{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,3\} \}$ is a subbasis as the union of elements equals $X$. The topology generated by this subbasis is all unions of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{S}$ which gives us $\mathcal{T} = \{\phi, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,2,3\} \}$.

Moreover $\mathcal{S}$ is itself a basis as it satisfies the conditions of being a basis. So we can generate a topology with finding the collection of all unions of elements of $\mathcal{S}$, which is worded differently compared to the case where we generate a topology on $\mathcal{S}$ as a subbasis. In this case the generated topology on $\mathcal{S}$ as a basis is $\mathcal{T'} = \{\phi, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,2,3\} \}$. We note $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T'}$.

Is it always the case that a topology generated by a subbasis yield to a same topology when the topology is generated by the same collection $\mathcal{S}$ but as a basis and not as a subbasis? What are other differences/similarities between the topologies in these case? I understand similar questions have been asked before but I am specifically asking about the differences/similarities that the same collection of sets $\mathcal{S}$ make when it is viewed as a subbasis and when viewed as a basis.

Comment: Your first topology is missing the element $\{1,2\}=\{1\}\cup\{2\}$

Comment: You are right! I edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: Well, eh...I don't think you should edit your question when it has received answers. Kinda makes some information in one of the answers seem pointless.

Comment: The answers were posted while I was editing.

Comment: It's not a big deal. The answers came before your edit so I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topology generated by the subbase $\mathcal{S}$ is not $\mathcal{T}$, but rather $\mathcal{T}'$: in the second paragraph you failed to take the union of $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$.

If a family $\mathcal{S}$ of subsets of $X$ is a base for a topology, that is also the topology generated by $\mathcal{S}$ as a subbase: it is already closed under finite intersections, so whichever way you view it, you’re just taking the closure under arbitrary unions. That is, every base for a topology is a subbase for that same topology.

Comment: but not every subbase is a base, correct? and if so could you please provide an example, possibly for a finite topological space?

Comment: @Rob: That’s correct: any collection of subsets of $X$ is a subbase for a topology on $X$, but not every collection is a base. Let $\mathscr{S}=\big\{\{0,1\},\{1,2\}\big\}$; this is a subbase for the topology $\big\{\varnothing,\{0,1\},\{1,2\},\{1\},\{0,1,2\}\big\}$ on the set $\{0,1,2\}$, but it is not a base for any topology.

Comment: Perfect! Can we state anytime that a subbase is also a base then the topology they generate make no difference? However, subbase becomes useful when it is not a base. Is this a fair observation?

Comment: @Rob: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Rob: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not always different. For instance, in your example, the set $T'$ can be taken as both a basis and as a subbasis, and when you generate a topology from each of these (in its own way), you get $T'$ back again.